# Как можно убрать пробелы во вложенных циклах?

Tags: python, циклы

Есть вот такое задание:

Вводится натуральное число N (то есть, положительное, целое).
Требуется создать двумерный (вложенный) список размером N x N элементов,
состоящий из всех единиц, а затем, в последний столбец записать пятерки.
Вывести этот список на экран в виде таблицы чисел, как показано в примере ниже.
P.S. Будьте внимательны в конце строк пробелов быть не должно!

```
 Sample Input:  4
 Sample Output:
 1 1 1 5
 1 1 1 5
 1 1 1 5
 1 1 1 5
```

И моё решение этого задания:
Без учёта P.S. Будьте внимательны в конце строк пробелов быть не должно!
Вопрос такой: Как можно убрать пробелы в конце этой матрицы?

```
N = 4       # int(input())
s = []
for i in range(N):
    i = 1
    s.append([i] * N)

for x in s:
    for j in x:
        x[-1] = 5
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Задание решилось вот так:

N = 4  # int(input())
s = []
a = 1
for i in range(N):
    s.append([a] * N)
for x in s:
    x[-1] = 5
    print(*x)

Answer (score 1):

Для корректного вывода можно использовать `join`:

```
for line in s:
    print(' '.join(map(str, line)))
```

Можно вывод в одну строку сократить:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, line)) for line in s))
```

А `x[-1] = 5` в вашем коде нужно вынести на уровень выше, т.е. в цикл `for x in s`

---

Однако я бы делал эту задачу как-то так:

```
N = 4       # int(input())

lst = [
    [1]*(N-1) + [5] for _ in range(N)
]

for line in lst:
    print(' '.join(map(str, line)))
```

А вот так выглядит однострочник:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, line)) for line in [[1]*(N-1)+[5] for _ in range(int(input()))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Без вложенных циклов и джойнов:

```
for x in s:
    x[-1] = 5
    print(*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

чисто в учебных целях:

```
l = [1]*N
s = [l]*N
l[N-1] = 5

for i in s:
    print(*i,sep=' ')
```

Comment: Прикольный фокус, но вряд ли соответствует заданию.

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласен. Это пример из серии "как не надо делать".

Answer (score 0):

По строчке на каждый пункт задания: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P0/BViEzr0QjM6@gtERDU5MrESgQHW2okJZfpBAPlFIoSsxLT9XI04zFIsQFEqoACSVaKVRE6xrGAnXrmnIVFIHMVIrJU9LLys/M01BSgDJyEws0ikuKdBQqNDUVEJo1Nf//NwcA)

```
n = int(input())
a = [[1 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
for x in a: x[-1] = -5
print("\n".join(" ".join(map(str, x)) for x in a))
```

Answer (score -1):

А вот ещё один ответ с комментариями по теме "Вложенные циклы":

[image: Автор: Den Romaniuk]

Comment: Прикладывайте код текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Или так:  n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n-1):
        print(1, end= " ")
    print(5)

Comment: Зачем цикл `for j`?

Comment: Не знаю. Это не мое решение.  Ответ взят из форума правильных решений... ;)

Comment: Значит, не такие уж они и правильные, эти решения, а как [90% кода в интернете](https://www.gunsmoker.ru/2010/05/90.html)

Comment: Мы ведь учимся ;)